# Ransack searching for instances with specific value in last of has_many associations

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm using [ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) for sorting and filtering in my rails project.

There's a `Child` model, it has many subscriptions for courses. `Course` has `period_id`. `Child` has a method `last_subscription_period`. 
Would be great to have an answer for any of the following questions:

1. What's the way of filtering children on this method results using ransack?
2. What's the SQL query for selecting children with last subscriptions having specific period_id?

Models:

```
Child has_many subscriptions
Subscription belongs_to child
Subscription belongs_to course
```

Columns

```
children: id
subscriptions: child_id, course_id, created_at
courses: period_id
```

Comment: For 2, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT l.child_id, co.period_id
FROM (
    SELECT s.child_id, s.course_id
    FROM (
        SELECT child_id, MAX(created_at) AS latest_subscription
        FROM subscriptions
        GROUP BY child_id
    ) AS l
    JOIN subscription AS s
        ON s.child_id = l.child_id
        AND s.created_at = l.latest_subscription
) AS l
JOIN courses AS co
ON co.id = l.course_id
```

Comment: I ended up making a ransacker with this query.