# Rails 6.1: Create a scope containing .first or .last through a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

In Rails 6.1, assuming two models:

- `PeriodicJob: has_many :executions`
- `Execution` with a field `state` that is either `succeeded` or `failed`

I want to run the query:

> Give me all `PeriodicJobs` which last (highest ID) execution has state `succeed`.

A potential solution would be raw SQL with a subquery, as pointed out in this other Stackoverflow question: [Ransack searching for instances with specific value in last of has_many associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48801103/ransack-searching-for-instances-with-specific-value-in-last-of-has-many-associat)

However, this seems overly complicated code for such a simple question in English. Given the power of Rails, I'd have expected to see something like:

```
PeriodicJob.joins(:executions).where(cool_trick_im_yet_unaware_of_to_get_last_ordered_by_id_execution: { state: 'succeeded' }
```

Does such a thing exist in Rails and how would it be applied to this example?

Answer (score 1):

One way of optimizing this for reading would be to setup a separate foreign key column and association as a "shortcut" to the latest execution:

```
class AddLatestExecutionToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :latest_execution, :execution
  end
end
```

```
class PeriodicJob < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :executions, 
    after_add: :set_latest_execution
  belongs_to :latest_execution, 
    optional: true,
    class_name: 'Execution'

  private

  def set_latest_execution(execution)
    update_attribute(:latest_execution_id, execution.id)
  end
end
```

This lets you do `PeriodicJob.eager_load(:latest_execution)` and avoid both a N+1 query and loading all the records off the executions table. This is especially important if you have a lot of executions per peroidic job.

The cost is that it requires an extra write query every time an execution is created.

If you want to limit this to just the latest success/failure you could add two columns:

```
class AddLatestExecutionToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :latest_successful_execution, :execution
    add_reference :latest_failed_execution, :execution
  end
end
```

```
class Execution ​< ApplicationRecord
  enum state: {
    ​succeeded: 'succeeded',
    ​failed:    'failed'
 ​ }
end
```

```
class PeriodicJob < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :executions, 
    after_add: :set_latest_execution
  belongs_to :latest_successful_execution, 
    optional: true,
    class_name: 'Execution'
  belongs_to :latest_failed_execution, 
    optional: true,
    class_name: 'Execution'

  private

  def set_latest_execution(execution)
    if execution.succeeded?
      update_attribute(:latest_successful_execution_id, execution.id)
    else
      update_attribute(:latest_failed_execution_id, execution.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I used this in weather station app where each station has thousands of observations and its the most performant solution by a mile. It might not be exactly right for your use case though.

Comment: +1 to this answer due to the performance boost for reads and the good explanation. I was however looking for a query that comes without any extra migrations, I'd rather not add redundancy to the DB and callbacks to each write.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using regular numeric ids, you can add a condition to the relationship. This will set a custom relationship on the model that will return the latest execution that is succeeded. THe has one macro will limit the 'collection' to one.

```rb
has_one :current_succeeded_execution, -> { where(state: "succeeded").reorder(id: :desc) }, class_name: 'Execution'
```

If you're using uuid, I would have set a default scope on those mdoels to order by created at asc to ensure the first one is always the oldest, ie the first one created. So then you could reorder to desc to get latest one

```rb
has_one :current_succeeded_execution, -> { where(state: "succeeded").reorder(created_at: :desc) }, class_name: 'Execution'
```

Comment: You're missing the `class_name: 'Execution'` option.

Comment: @max thanks for that :D I had to rush to finish as I was getting called away when answering :P

Comment: The has_one scope in the answer is yet missing the lambda operator (`->`)

Comment: This solution does not appear to work: `PeriodicJob.joins(:current_succeeded_execution).pluck(:id)` returns a `PeriodicJob` ID for every succeeded `Execution`: `[14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15]`. It includes IDs of jobs whose last execution has failed, which is not what was asked ("Give me all `PeriodicJobs` which last (highest ID) execution has state `succeed`.")